# Prove that $\def\Aut{\operatorname{Aut}}\Aut(\mathbf{Z_{n}})\simeq \mathbf{Z_{n}^{*}}$

Tags: group-theory

I am writing another exam in Algebra this week and this time the main topic is automorphism. I was again going through the example exercises and exams from previous years and this problem is giving me a hard time to understand:

Prove that for group of automorphisms $\def\Aut{\operatorname{Aut}}\Aut(\mathbf{Z_{n}})$ holds  $\Aut(\mathbf{Z_{n}})\simeq \mathbf{Z_{n}^{*}}$ where $\mathbf{Z_{n}^{*}}=\{1 \leq k \leq q | \gcd(k,n)=1\} $.

My main issue with this problem is that it seems very "general" and I don't really know how to address it with any of the techniques we have used.

Could you please show me some ways this could be approached? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that a homomorphism is determined by the image of $\overline{1}$.

Now consider which restrictions you get from the fact that the homomorphism is injective.

Comment: Could you please give a little bit more hint here? I understand the first part, but don't understand the statement with restrictions (maybe just that I don't know the right English translation to Czech). Thank you very much!

Comment: If you are just interested in a homomorphism the image of 1 can be any element of the group. However, if the homomorphism should be injective you need that the image of 1 is an element of order n; this is what I meant by "restrictions", so restrictions on the choice of the image of 1.